# MS Access 2010, Distinct in a Report?

Tags: report, ms-access-2010

I have a report that is based on a query of diagnoses (for example diabetes). The report returns a list of patients with that diagnosis.  The problem is if john Q has diabetes xyz and diabetes 123, so if I run the report to give me a list of everyone with diabetes it will retun his name twice.  I really don't want to change the particular query that this based on, I just want distinct name in the report. Is there a way to use distinct for a report or any other way of limiting the names to just once in the report? Or am I going to have to write a distinct query just for this report?

Answer (score 0):

either edit the query by changing SELECT to
    SELECT DISTINCT

or set the report to use grouping,  you can Group by Name (or more likely, by a patient ID so two people with the same name don't get combined) - it's as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-6a58e9ab-9f74-4689-83b6-c63cddb2c7f9?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

if you exclude listing the types of diabetes you will get each person on one line, if you include the types of diabetes you will get each person's details used as a heading with the types of diabetes indented

If the report already exists you can edit it by using the Grouping and Sorting option https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-6a58e9ab-9f74-4689-83b6-c63cddb2c7f9?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA#__migbm_0